# How to make that a parameter reads more than one value on stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I'm making a stored procedure to know the future dates in which a maintenance should be scheduled, but there are a lot of machines on the table but procedure only calls one.

The Declares that I used are for it to call the data of each machine and do the cycle to know the future dates in the range given

```
@name varchar(50),
                @FechaHasta datetime,
                @Result     DATETIME = null OUTPUT)
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @JOBNO NVARCHAR(50)
    SELECT  @JOBNO = JOBNO FROM PMMASTER INNER JOIN LABORMP 
    ON PMMASTER.PMID = LABORMP.PMID INNER JOIN PMMSCHEDULE
    ON PMMASTER.PMID = PMMSCHEDULE.PMID 
    where EMPLOYEENAME = @name AND PMMSCHEDULE.CYCLETYPE =2 and PMMSCHEDULE.SETTING2 IS NOT NULL and PMMSCHEDULE.SETTING1 IS NOT NULL

    DECLARE @DATELAST DATETIME
        SELECT @DATELAST = DATELAST FROM PMMSCHEDULE INNER JOIN PMMASTER
        ON PMMASTER.PMID = PMMSCHEDULE.PMID INNER JOIN LABORMP
        ON PMMASTER.PMID = LABORMP.PMID 
        WHERE JOBNO in (@JOBNO) and EMPLOYEENAME =@name 

    DECLARE @SETTING1 INT
        SELECT @SETTING1 = SETTING1 FROM PMMSCHEDULE INNER JOIN PMMASTER
        ON PMMASTER.PMID = PMMSCHEDULE.PMID INNER JOIN LABORMP
        ON PMMASTER.PMID = LABORMP.PMID 
        WHERE JOBNO in (@JOBNO)  AND EMPLOYEENAME = @name 

        DECLARE @SETTING2 INT
        SELECT @SETTING2 = SETTING2 FROM PMMSCHEDULE INNER JOIN PMMASTER
        ON PMMASTER.PMID = PMMSCHEDULE.PMID INNER JOIN LABORMP
        ON PMMASTER.PMID = LABORMP.PMID 
        WHERE JOBNO in (@JOBNO)  AND EMPLOYEENAME = @name 

DECLARE
    @DateFirst  INT
SELECT  @DateFirst  =   @@DateFirst

/* Today */ 
DECLARE 
        @TodaysDate     DATETIME    
-- Finding today's date after resetting the time to midnight 
SELECT  @TodaysDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 101), 101) 

/* Todays WeekDay */ 
DECLARE
    @TodaysWeekDay  INT
SELECT  @TodaysWeekDay  =   DATEPART(dw, @TodaysDate)

/* Selected WeekDay */ 
DECLARE 
    @WeekDay    INT 
SELECT  @WeekDay    =   CHARINDEX('1',  @Setting2) 

/* Schedule Date */ 
DECLARE
        @ScheduleDate   DATETIME 
-- Find the starting schedule date. If the schedule date is in a previous  
-- week, adjust to the most recent week in the schedule 
SELECT  @ScheduleDate   =   @DATELAST 

-- Adjust scheduled date to closest possible week day
SELECT  @ScheduleDate = DATEADD(dd, @WeekDay - DATEPART(dw, @ScheduleDate), @ScheduleDate)

-- Add cycles until a possible date is met  
WHILE   (@ScheduleDate  <   @TodaysDate)
    SELECT  @ScheduleDate   =   DATEADD(wk, @Setting1, @ScheduleDate)

IF  (@ScheduleDate  <=  @DATELAST)
    SELECT  @ScheduleDate   =   DATEADD(wk, @Setting1, @ScheduleDate)

SELECT  @Result =   @ScheduleDate

SELECT @Result AS RESULTADO

SET DATEFIRST   @DateFirst


WHILE(@Result <@FechaHasta)
    BEGIN
        IF(@Result <@FechaHasta)

            SELECT  @Result =   DATEADD(WK, @Setting1,  @Result)
            SET IDENTITY_INSERT [00TblFecha] ON 

            INSERT INTO dbo.[00TblFecha](idFecha,jobno,fecha)VALUES(3,@JOBNO,@Result)

            SET IDENTITY_INSERT[00TblFecha] OFF     
            print @Result
        end
```

Comment: So you posted a wall of text which contains a while loop. Is there actually a question here? If so, you need to explain what you are asking. As a side note, there is no reason you need to use a while loop for inserts like this.

Comment: Sorry my question was how to make the stored procedure to use more than one machine to make the cycle?

Comment: That makes no sense. Keep in mind that we don't know your system, we have no idea what your project is and we can't see your screen. All we have to work with is this extremely vague description of the problem.

Comment: By "machine" are you referring to servers? Or to records in a table (conceptual entities)?

Comment: Records in a table

Comment: How?    By programming.    Did you want to make your question more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few options:
 - Use table valued parameter, which is preferable: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)
 - Use XML parameter
 - Use comma delimited list. 
 - Do the loop over all of your "machines"

By the way, exclude usage of @@DateFirst in your SP. Anyway you do not use it.